# Python Partial Harmonics

Tags: python

Could someone help check why the result is always one and let me know what I did wrong? Thanks

Correct result should be: 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 == 1.83333333333.

```
x = int(input("Enter n: "))
assert x > 0, "n must be greater than zero!"

def one_over_n(x):

    result = 0

    for n in range(x):
        n += 1
        result += 1 / n
    return result
r = one_over_n(x)
print("one_over_n( {0:d} ): {1:f}" .format(x, r))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work correctly on python 3, but not in python 2

```
>>> 1/2
0
```

That means you are just adding zeroes, to one. You will need to change either numerator or denominator to a float number e.g. `1/2.0`, so change your code to

```
result += 1.0 / n
```

See [Pep 238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) to see why it was changed in python 3.

btw floating point numbers can't represent all fractions, so if you are just adding fractions, you can use `Fraction` class e.g.

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction as F
>>> F(1,1) + F(1,2) + F(1,3)
Fraction(11, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, to force Python 2 perform division as you expect (rather than integer division), add:

```
from __future__ import division
```